# Learning Prolog : solving crossword problem in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to learn Prolog and I've an exercise and I couldn't solve it.
Here's what I have to do:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSJqK.png

and this is the code which I tried:-

```
word(zombifies, [z,o,m,b,i,f,i,e,s]).
word(akecabele, [a,k,e,c,a,b,e,l,e]).
word(brickwork, [b,r,i,c,k,w,o,r,k]).
word(backcheck, [b,a,c,k,c,h,e,c,k]).
word(acmrremad, [a,c,m,r,r,e,m,a,d]).
word(nhgwpfabz, [n,h,g,w,p,f,a,b,z]).
word(jellybean, [j,e,l,l,y,b,e,a,n]).
word(aerreoded, [a,e,r,r,e,o,d,e,d]).

crossword(H1,H2,H3,H4,V1,V2,V3,V4):-
    word(H1, [_,H1V1,_,H1V2,_,H1V3,_,H1V4,_]),
    word(H2, [_,H2V1,_,H2V2,_,H2V3,_,H2V4,_]),
    word(H3, [_,H3V1,_,H3V2,_,H3V3,_,H3V4,_]),
    word(H4, [_,H4V1,_,H4V2,_,H4V3,_,H4V4,_]),

    word(V1, [_,H1V1,_,H2V1,_,H3V1,_,H4V1,_]),
    word(V2, [_,H1V2,_,H2V2,_,H3V2,_,H4V2,_]),
    word(V3, [_,H1V3,_,H2V3,_,H3V3,_,H4V3,_]),
    word(V4, [_,H1V4,_,H2V4,_,H3V4,_,H4V4,_]),
H1\=V1,
H2\=V2,
H3\=V3,
H4\=V4.
```

but always when I run this code it returns false.
so what I can do to modify this code to run correctly ?

**Edit**
There is a final solution for this problem in this picture:-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QiEw.png

Comment: What makes you think there *is* a solution?

Comment: Your "solution" uses the word "earreoded", which is not one of you words.

Comment: no I used it in my code and it's found in V2 in the picture which I uploaded, so it's in my code and in solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not find a solution because there is no solution with word `aerreoded`. However, when word `earreoded` is included in the set of words, two solutions can be found.

```
word(zombifies, [z,o,m,b,i,f,i,e,s]).
word(akecabele, [a,k,e,c,a,b,e,l,e]).
word(brickwork, [b,r,i,c,k,w,o,r,k]).
word(backcheck, [b,a,c,k,c,h,e,c,k]).
word(acmrremad, [a,c,m,r,r,e,m,a,d]).
word(nhgwpfabz, [n,h,g,w,p,f,a,b,z]).
word(jellybean, [j,e,l,l,y,b,e,a,n]).
word(aerreoded, [a,e,r,r,e,o,d,e,d]).
word(earreoded, [e,a,r,r,e,o,d,e,d]). % include this new word!

crossword(H1,H2,H3,H4,V1,V2,V3,V4):-
    word(H1, [_,H1V1,_,H1V2,_,H1V3,_,H1V4,_]),
    word(H2, [_,H2V1,_,H2V2,_,H2V3,_,H2V4,_]),
    word(H3, [_,H3V1,_,H3V2,_,H3V3,_,H3V4,_]),
    word(H4, [_,H4V1,_,H4V2,_,H4V3,_,H4V4,_]),
    word(V1, [_,H1V1,_,H2V1,_,H3V1,_,H4V1,_]),
    word(V2, [_,H1V2,_,H2V2,_,H3V2,_,H4V2,_]),
    word(V3, [_,H1V3,_,H2V3,_,H3V3,_,H4V3,_]),
    word(V4, [_,H1V4,_,H2V4,_,H3V4,_,H4V4,_]),
    H1 \= V1,
    H2 \= V2,
    H3 \= V3,
    H4 \= V4.
```

Running example:

```
?- crossword(H1,H2,H3,H4,V1,V2,V3,V4).
H1 = backcheck,
H2 = brickwork,
H3 = zombifies,
H4 = jellybean,
V1 = earreoded,
V2 = akecabele,
V3 = nhgwpfabz,
V4 = acmrremad ;
H1 = earreoded,
H2 = akecabele,
H3 = nhgwpfabz,
H4 = acmrremad,
V1 = backcheck,
V2 = brickwork,
V3 = zombifies,
V4 = jellybean ;
false.
```

As you can see, no solution containing the word `aerreoded` is found.

**IMPROVED VERSION**

You can make your code run faster by reordering the conditions in the definition of predicate `crossword/8`, so that fails occur as early as possible (that will reduce the number of backtracks/inferences needed to find the answers).

```
faster_crossword(H1,H2,H3,H4,V1,V2,V3,V4):-
    word(H1, [_,H1V1,_,H1V2,_,H1V3,_,H1V4,_]),
    word(V1, [_,H1V1,_,H2V1,_,H3V1,_,H4V1,_]),
    H1 \= V1,
    word(H2, [_,H2V1,_,H2V2,_,H2V3,_,H2V4,_]),
    word(V2, [_,H1V2,_,H2V2,_,H3V2,_,H4V2,_]),
    H2 \= V2,
    word(H3, [_,H3V1,_,H3V2,_,H3V3,_,H3V4,_]),
    word(V3, [_,H1V3,_,H2V3,_,H3V3,_,H4V3,_]),
    H3 \= V3,
    word(H4, [_,H4V1,_,H4V2,_,H4V3,_,H4V4,_]),
    word(V4, [_,H1V4,_,H2V4,_,H3V4,_,H4V4,_]),
    H4 \= V4.
```

To compare both versions, you can use [`forall/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2) (to generate all solutions) and [`time/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=time/1) (to print running time statistics).

Empirical results:

```
?- time(forall(crossword(H1,H2,H3,H4,V1,V2,V3,V4), writeln([H1,H2,H3,H4,V1,V2,V3,V4]))).
[backcheck,brickwork,zombifies,jellybean,earreoded,akecabele,nhgwpfabz,acmrremad]
[earreoded,akecabele,nhgwpfabz,acmrremad,backcheck,brickwork,zombifies,jellybean]
% 7,411 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
true.

?- time(forall(faster_crossword(H1,H2,H3,H4,V1,V2,V3,V4), writeln([H1,H2,H3,H4,V1,V2,V3,V4]))).
[backcheck,brickwork,zombifies,jellybean,earreoded,akecabele,nhgwpfabz,acmrremad]
[earreoded,akecabele,nhgwpfabz,acmrremad,backcheck,brickwork,zombifies,jellybean]
% 48 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
true.
```

Comment: I tried this code also and returned false it doesn't return any solution it returns false only

Comment: Thats sounds very strange... This code works perfectly with SWI-Prolog compiler! What compiler are you using?

Comment: I also using SWI-Prolog, I wrote a code in file with extension .pl then open it with SWI-Prolog and write function name in compiler.

Comment: Maybe you are calling the predicate the wrong way... You must copy and paste the source-code in the editor, save it and, then, compile it. After that, you must copy and paste the predicate call (the query) in the system prompt (?- ). Are you doing that?

Comment: yes, I do that.
write a code in my editor, save it and open pl file with SWI-Prolog and write function name with its parameters in prompt